# How to calculate local time at timezone given GMT/UTC offset in Perl?

Tags: perl, timezone

I need to find out what is local time at a given location. I have GMT/UTC offset for that location. I am trying to get a time duration by taking a difference between deadline set in that time zone to trigger emails being sent out when deadline is met in that perticular time zone.

Ex.If deadline is set in Seattle to be Sept 10, 2011 12:00:00 GMT -7:00 now if I am in UK I need to calculate what time is now in Seattle given GMT offset -7:00 once I get that I can calculate the difference if the difference is 0 then I will sent out an email saying deadline is met.

How can I do the time calculation part in Perl?

Please help.

Thanks,
Sunyl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a DateTime object, and compare it to `DateTime->now`. The DateTime object is aware of the time zone associated with the timestamp therein, so it can do what you want with no fuss.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use DateTime qw( );
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => '%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z',
   locale   => 'en',
   on_error => 'croak',
);

my $target = 'Sep 10, 2011 12:00:00 GMT-0700';

my $target_dt = $strp->parse_datetime($target);
my $now_dt    = DateTime->now();

if ($now_dt > $target_dt) {
   say "It's too late";
} else {
   say "It's not too late";
}

$target_dt->set_time_zone('local');
say "The deadline is $target_dt, local time";
```

Above, I assumed you miscopied the date format. If the date is formatted as you provided, you won't be able to use Strptime because the timestamp uses nonstandard names for the months and a nonstandard format for the offset.

```
my @months = qw( ... Sept ... );
my %months = map { $months[$_] => $_+1 } 0..$#months;

my ($m,$d,$Y,$H,$M,$S,$offS,$offH,$offM) = $target =~
      /^(\w+) (\d+), (\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+) GMT ([+-])(\d+):(\d+)\z/
   or die;

my $target_dt = DateTime->new(
   year      => $Y,
   month     => $months{$m},
   day       => 0+$d,
   hour      => 0+$H,
   minute    => 0+$M,
   second    => 0+$S,
   time_zone => sprintf("%s%04d", $offS, $offH * 100 + $offM),
);
```

- [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime)
- [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime)

Comment: @Sunyl, I've appended two lines to the first snippet. I should help clear up your doubt.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the DateTime module from CPAN to do time calculations.

http://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime

It's got time zone stuff that you can leverage as well. Should be pretty straight forward as the documentation is pretty clear.

Specifically,

```
$dt->subtract_datetime( $datetime )

This method returns a new DateTime::Duration object representing the difference between the two    dates. The duration is relative to the object from which $datetime is subtracted. For example:

   2003-03-15 00:00:00.00000000
-  2003-02-15 00:00:00.00000000
-------------------------------
= 1 month

Note that this duration is not an absolute measure of the amount of time between the two datetimes, because the length of a month varies, as well as due to the presence of leap seconds.
```

Hope that helps!

Edit:

Also this is probably important/will make life easier,

```
use UTC for all calculations

If you do care about time zones (particularly DST) or leap seconds, try to use non-UTC time zones for presentation and user input only. Convert to UTC immediately and convert back to the local time zone for presentation:

my $dt = DateTime->new( %user_input, time_zone => $user_tz );
$dt->set_time_zone('UTC');

# do various operations - store it, retrieve it, add, subtract, etc.

$dt->set_time_zone($user_tz);
print $dt->datetime;
```